# How to split HTML textarea element into array of lines in Java

Tags: java, split, textarea

How to split HTML textarea element into array of lines in Java

Comment: Where are you getting it from? What kind of object is it in? Can you post the code you have already?

Comment: String notes = request.getParameter("notes");
notes is a textarea html element

Answer (score 4):

If you mean Java and not JavaScript (assuming you have a JSP system):

```
String[] lines = myTextArea.getText().split("\\n");
```

or

```
String[] lines = request.getParameter("textarea").split("\\n");
```

---

For JavaScript:

```
var lines = document.getElementById("myTextArea").value.split('\\n');
```

Comment: Java has the /REGEX/ notation?

Comment: No, it should be "\\n", not /\n/.

Comment: I'm not using JTextArea so getText() wont work. I'm getting the textarea content with request.getParameter("textarea") which returns string. No it is not JS.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, get the text and pass it to a method like:

```
private String[] split(String s) {
        if (s==null) {
            return new String[0];
        }

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s,"\n");
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
            list.add(st.nextToken());
        }

        return (String[]) list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
}
```